# Table parameters saved in a central document

Tags: asciidoc

I am using two attributes for table parameters

:table1: frame="none", grid = "none", stripes=none

:table2: frame="topbot", grid = "rows", options="header"

I want to save them in an different file as I want to use them because I want to reuse themn in many different files. How do I get the other files to know these attributes?

Comment: Use [include](https://docs.asciidoctor.org/asciidoc/latest/directives/include/) to include the different file.

Answer (score 0):

For the specific problem, Asciidoc 'include' directive may be enough.
You do not even need to put that part into a separate file. You can put a

```
// tag::table_attributes[]
:table1: frame="none", grid = "none", stripes=none
:table2: frame="topbot", grid = "rows", options="header"
// end::table_attributes[]
```

and then you can

```
include::the_original.adoc[tag=table_attributes]
```

in other files. (I did not try it, but it should work.)

When things like that come I usually use the Jamal preprocessor I created

https://github.com/verhas/jamal

that also has snipped include possibilities and many other programming capabilities.